# Jquery Autocomplete hightlight the non-matching text like Google

Tags: pattern-matching, jquery-autocomplete

I am using the jQuery Autocomplete plugin and I would like to implement the same thign like in Google's autocomplete:

I have searched for this, but all the examples are showing, how can I highlight the matching word, but I would like the oposite one:

For example if I type: acc -> I would like to have acc**ount** , acc**ount manager**

Has someone some solution for this?

Thanks
Nik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be be a CSS issue.  I'll use Twitter Bootstrap Typeahead as an example.

These are the plugin defaults that matter:

```
menu: '<ul class="typeahead dropdown-menu"></ul>'
item: '<li><a href="#"></a></li>'
```

The highlighter simply wraps the highlighted section in a  tag like so:

```
highlighter: function (item) {
  var query = this.query.replace(/[\-\[\]{}()*+?.,\\\^$|#\s]/g, '\\$&')
  return item.replace(new RegExp('(' + query + ')', 'ig'), function ($1, match) {
    return '<strong>' + match + '</strong>'
  })
}
```

A simple typeahead would look like:

```
<ul class="typeahead dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#"><strong>test</strong>ing</a></li>
</ul>
```

Which means in the simplest setup, you can add some basic CSS like so

```
.typeahead  > li > a {
font-weight: bold;
}

.typeahead  > li > a strong {
font-weight: normal;
}
```